# How do you sort data with multiindex (columns) dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

First, please forgive my bad vocabulary. Im still struggling with the correct terms, and have just discovered that I have created a multiindexed dataframe, which Im trying to learn how to manipulate.

The multiindex dataframe has 30 rows and 546 columns, and looks like a bigger version of this:

|  | A |  |  | B |  |  | C |  |  | D |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | aa | bb | cc | aa | bb | cc | aa | bb | cc | aa | bb | cc |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 24 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 10 | 12 | 5 | 9 | 21 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 23 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 9 | 13 | 6 | 10 | 22 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 | 22 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 12 | 8 | 14 | 24 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3 | 21 | 10 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 8 | 11 | 10 | 12 | 21 |

The index is a timestamp date, and the top level (level 0?) column indexes A, B, C, D, etc each have the same 91 second level (level 1?) members: aa, bb, cc, etc

Since there are 546 columns in total, and 91 'level 1' columns, there must be 6 'level 0' columns. I cant see them cos the tables so big it just shows the first and last.

In reality, its a table of stock data pulled off yahoo where A, B, C are the (6) financial values like close, volume, high, etc and aa, bb, cc, etc are the (91) company codes.

Id like to learn how to do the following:

1. How to pull off a list of the 'level 0' column names.
2. How to pull off a list of the 'level 1' column names.
3. For 1 row (date), pull out the data for ALL 'level 0' and ONE 'level 1' index. (For example, all financial data for one company on one day).
4. For 1 row (date), ONE 'level 0' with ALL 'level 0' data. For example, volume data for all companies on one day.

Ive been trying things like:

```
df.loc[:,(['A','B'],['aa,'bb', 'cc'])]
df.loc['2023-01-02', :]
```

which work, but I cant sort the brackets and colons right to do the above stuff.

Also,

```
 df.loc[:,(['A','D'],['aa,'cc','ff'])]
```

and

```
df.loc['2023-01-05':,([A,C],[aa,dd])]
```

work, but

```
df.loc['2023-01-05',([A:],[aa,dd])]
```

and

```
df.loc['2023-01-05',(A:,[aa,dd])]
```

give invalid syntax. Can anyone explain, or maybe point me towards a tutorial that will help with the level definitions and round/square brackets and colons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull a list of *level* column names,  you can use `get_level_values`:

```
df.columns.get_level_values(0)
#Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'], dtype='object')

df.columns.get_level_values(1)
#Index(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc'], dtype='object')

df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
#Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')

df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()
#Index(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], dtype='object')
```

For 3 and 4, `pd.IndexSlice` would be convenient to use:

```
# all level zero data for a specific level one index
df.loc['2023-01-05', pd.IndexSlice[:, 'aa']]

#A  aa     3
#B  aa     3
#C  aa     4
#D  aa    10
#Name: 2023-01-05, dtype: int64

# all level one data for a specific level zero index

df.loc['2023-01-05', pd.IndexSlice['A', :]]
#A  aa     3
#   bb    21
#   cc    10
#Name: 2023-01-05, dtype: int64
```

Comment: So easy when you know how! Thanks, Psidom, works perfectly!